# Is X-LConn-RunAs exposed through the Social Business Toolkit?

Tags: impersonation, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

In IBM Connections, we need to post topics and reply from a java (not web) application.
I noticed in the [API Documentation](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API%20Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Creating_a_standalone_forum_topic_programmatically_ic50&content=apicontent) that you can provide a HTTP HEADER value to post a topic or reply on behalf of another user (impersonation).

We would like to use the Social Business Toolkit for this purpose, but the question is, **how** ?

I could not find a reference to *X-LConn-RunAs*. 
And do we need to configure security similar to the security for activitystreams ? Or is it enough to be administrator of the forum ?

Comment: it is not directly supported.  We did no work in supporting the X-LConn-RunAs.  please open a github issue and we'll tag it as an enhancement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported through the SBT at this moment in time